# Extract theme from Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

I use Magento 1.9.2.4 and have a theme installed on it, but it was another developer that install that and we don't have the original files anymore.

Is there a way to "extract" the theme files using FTP or something?

Looks like the theme files are located in the folders: **app, js and skin** in the folder with the respective theme name; but I am not sure if I am missing something or if this structure can be different from a theme to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, structure of the theme is the same like you explained and you can copy them from ftp.

Theme files can be in following places:

1. `app/code/[local or community]/ModuleName` **(this is only if theme has some extra feature, like backend config framework etc)**
2. `app/design/frontend/default/[ThemeName]`
3. `js`
4. `skin/frontend` **(you should check what structure they are located in, simply inspect element frontend and check the one of the css location)**
5. `skin/adminhtml` **(if theme has admin UI)**

**To know theme name, you can go to `System > Configuration > Design` and check the name.**

Comment: In my case there is also the "media" folder :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna start by saying only do this in new directories some where on your local machine. Don't do this in a production, staging, or even local dev. env.  I will also note that you should create a branch before doing any work if you have an existing repos.

The best was to do this would be to use git and composer.

If you have git and composer set up already, fantastic! If not well... git init!

Fist step create a local git repo. (BitBucket is a good service for free private repos.)

Find a [.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Magento.gitignore) add that to your repo and commit

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -a "add .gitignore"
```

Now add all your magento files.

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -a "add magento"
$ git push
```

If you use the .gitignore github suggests you should have added pretty much only your theme files to the repo. From here you can use `$ git clone` in a new empty dir to have a semi extracted version of your theme.

If you want to take it a step further you can [require magento as a dependency](https://github.com/firegento/magento/blob/master/README.md) with [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) using the [Magento Composer Installer](https://github.com/Cotya/magento-composer-installer/blob/3.0/README.md). Then in your composer.json `extra` block set force override to true. Once you get composer to run you should be able to run `git status` and see a bunch of deleted files. Add those changes to your repo and push. After a successful push you can delete every thing in you dir and reclone the repo. You should now be left with only your theme files.

In theory this should work don't make any permanent changes. And Feel free to ask me questions.